# Is it possible to start Fancybox on page load with a youtube video automatic and close at end automatic?

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, fancybox-2

Is it possible to start Fancybox on page load with a Youtube video automatically and to close automatically at the end of the video? (A kind of intro)

Comment: Have you tried it yourself yet?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Take the example at the [fancybox website](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful) (tips & tricks No.15), and tweak it to your needs.

First, you would need to load the youtube player API (apart from the jQuery and fancybox js and css files of course)

```
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
```

Then built the `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()` function with the fancybox custom script inside of it to launch the video.

Then, inside the fancybox `beforeShow` callback, set a listener for the end of the video and close fancybox using the method `$.fancybox.close()` like :

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fancybox({
            href: "http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque&autoplay=1",
            type: "iframe",
            beforeShow: function () {
                // Find the iframe ID
                var id = $.fancybox.inner.find('iframe').attr('id');
                // Create video player object and add event listeners
                var player = new YT.Player(id, {
                    events: {
                        'onStateChange': function (event) {
                            if (event.data === 0) {
                                $.fancybox.close();
                            } // if
                        } // onStateChange
                    } // events
                }); // YT.Player
            } // beforeShow
        }); // fancybox
    }); // ready
} // onYouTubePlayerAPIReady
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C7y9s/)**

Comment: I have done this this way, it works great, but the only issue is that it takes sooo long to load. Do you know any way to improve this? Thanks !

Comment: @pablito.aven Does the JSFIDDLE demo do the same? Try using it as your base code to test your own video

Comment: The jsfiddle loads faster, I guess it might be my web has too many plugins in it. Is there any way I can ensure this video fancybox is open before anything else is done, and then load the entire web while the video is being played? Would you be able to guide me on this? Thank you really very much buddy.

Comment: I have placed the `<script>` tag which runs this code at the `<head>` section of the html, before loading any css or js files(except the ones needed for the fancybox and video), or rendering the web. Is there any way to wait for the fancybox to be opened before continuing with the render of the page? So this way it does not kill user's RAM and allow the video to load faster. Instruct me if I am wrong at some point please.

Comment: @pablito.aven It doesn't really make any difference to load the files at the top of your page since the plugin will run until the DOM is ready anyways. Read more https://api.jquery.com/ready/ What you have to do is to find out how to optimize your page